# webpack command in psake script is failing the task

Tags: webpack, psake

In my psake task, the following commands:

```
exec { npm install --no-optional --no-shrinkwrap --no-package-lock }
exec { npm run prod-build }
```

with this npm script:

```
"prod-build": "webpack --config ./webpack.prod.js --display errors-only"
```

Gives the following error and fails my script:

```
89 char:12 +     exec { npm run prod-build } +            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [<<==>>] Exception: clean-webpack-plugin: <projectdir>\Build\release\scripts\dist has been removed.
```

That's not an error or a failure, so I'm unsure as to why it's causing the build to fail.

When I adjust the npm run command to the following (No longer using psake's exec):

```
npm run prod-build
Write-Host "Run exit code: $lastexitcode"
```

I get the same error message and it doesn't hit the `Write-Host` line. When I try the following:

```
npm run prod-build -verbose
Write-Host "Run exit code: $lastexitcode"
```

I receive this error (again no exit code)"

```
Error: 8/15/2018 10:25:03 AM: 
At C:\workspace\vso\hop_hospiceorderportal\build\psake.ps1:92 char:5 +  npm run prod-build -verbose +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ [<<==>>] Exception: npm info it worked if it ends with
 ok
psake.ps1 failed
```

When I run the `npm run prod-build` command directly in the console it works as expected. It seems like something with psake is throwing it off.

Comment: What is the exit code from that npm command?

Comment: @GaryEwanPark I added more info to the question.

Comment: Do you see different behaviour if you run the npm command directly in the shell?

Comment: Yes, it works as expected.

Comment: fwiw, I scrapped using psake and started using Cake. So far so good!

Comment: Good choice! I am in no way biased about your decision 

Comment: Why didn't you tell me earlier!!?!?!? :-)